# Different methods of copying arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm going through this question on [Practice-It](https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/cs1/labs/lab7/swapAll) provided by my school. Well, I graduated a couple of weeks ago and was going through this website before jumping on leetcode.

Anyways, this method `swapAll` makes the two arrays that are passed as parameters copy one another.

For those having trouble viewing the problem,

> Write a method named `swapAll` that accepts two arrays of integers as parameters and swaps their entire contents.
> You may assume that the arrays passed are not null and are the same length.
>
> For example, if the following arrays are passed:
>
> ````java
> int[] a1 = {11, 42, -5, 27, 0, 89};
> int[] a2 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
> swapAll(a1, a2);
>
> After the call, the arrays should store the following elements:
>
> ```java
> a1: {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
> a2: {11, 42, -5, 27, 0, 89}
> ````

I actually found two solutions to this problem

```
public static void swapAll(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] c = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = c[i];
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void swapAll(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] c = new int[a.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(c, 0, b, 0, a.length);
}
```

but I was wondering if one method has superiority in terms of runtime/memory

Comment: `arraycopy()` is faster for native data types.

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer another option. One that doesn't involve creating an entire unnecessary temporary array. Basically, the first approach but use a single temporary `int` instead of an array. Something like,

```
public static void swapAll(int[] a, int[] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. The first 'solution' in the question is bad, because you don't need a second array. This is the proper way. But when it comes to performance, `System.arrayCopy()` is so much better.